# Screencast Keys Not Working on 3.0+

Tags: add-on, screencast

Anyone know why screencast keys won't work on Blender 3.0+? I don't think it's an addon conflict (It works in 2.93 with all the same addons installed.) Hoping this is a known thing/quick fix. Here's the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.2\3.2\scripts\modules\addon_utils.py", line 371, in enable
    mod.register()
  File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\screencast_keys\__init__.py", line 104, in register
    utils.bl_class_registry.BlClassRegistry.register()
  File "C:\Users\Jay\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.2\scripts\addons\screencast_keys\utils\bl_class_registry.py", line 58, in register
    bpy.utils.register_class(class_["class"])
ValueError: register_class(...): already registered as a subclass 'SK_OT_ScreencastKeys'
```

Comment: for me...it works. Maybe you can share some more information like error message or when it is not working? when enabling? when installing?

Comment: did you remove the folder screencast in your blender/scripts/add-ons directory? it sounds like it is "double" installed

Comment: Double install seems to have been the issue. Thanks!!!

Comment: glad i could help